# Saving JDBC db data as shared state Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an MSSQL table as a data source and I would like to save some kind of the processing offset in the form of the timestamp (it is one of the table's columns). So it would be possible to process the data from the latest offset. I would like to save as some kind of shared state between Spark sessions. I have researched [shared state in Spark session](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-SharedState.html), however, I did not find the way to store this offset in the shared state. So is it possible to use existing Spark constructs to perform this task?

Comment: Hi @Cassie, so this offset will be the timestamp where you should start retrieving data from MSSQL correct? Also how you are planing to update this (i.e retrieving it with Spark is an option)?

Comment: That's right it's a timestamp. I am planning to update it by running Spark batch job again, but I don't want to process all the data just the data starting from the offset

Comment: Since you already have MSSQL why don't you create a table which keeps a run log of your spark job. Every time your spark job starts read last updated date from DB and when job ends update that value to new offset.

Comment: OK that's clear now. One more thing, you want to store the offset for consistency between Spark sessions (i.e all sessions must have the same offset) or just to avoid to query SQL Server constantly?

Comment: Both for consistency and avoiding reprocessing of old data

Comment: Hi Casie, in your case by consistency I mean if you have a requirement to share the same offset between your sessions? For instance the 1st job retrieve the offset, the next one should necessarily use the same offset etc

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would like to achieve

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would like to achieve

Comment: OK I see. So you retrieve it initially from the MSSQL (a query such as `select max(offset) from tbl` should be relatively fast when offset is indexed even more) then you need something more elegant than Hive I guess :)  to transfer it between sessions

Comment: I thought about using Kafka for the offsets storage and then using it for reading from MSSQL.

Comment: Hive, in memory storage (Apache Ignite, redis) none of those is used already in your project? I agree, by the way, that it would be super overhead to introduce any of them just for one variable. In the case that I am not able to find an elegant way to pass it between sessions I would go just for Hive/SparkSQL with `df.createGlobalTempView("settings")`

Comment: Kafka is not storage is a message queue for supporting fail-over and very high throughput. Kafka would be the biggest overhead of all just for one variable I think.

Comment: I believe there should be a way to pass values between sessions we need to investigate it a bit more.

Comment: Well, we already use Kafka in the project. So we would just have to add new topic with offsets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no official built-in feature supporting passing data between sessions in Spark. As alternative I would consider the following options/suggestions:

1. First the offset column must be an indexed field in MSSQL in order to be able to query it fast.
2. If there is already an in-memory (i.e Redis, Apache Ignite) system installed and used by your project I would store there the offset.
3. I wouldn't use a message queue system such as Kafka because once you consume one message you will need to resend it therefore that would't make sense.
4. As solution I would prefer to save it in the filesystem or in Hive even if it would add extra overhead since you will have only one value in that table. In the case of the filesystem of course the performance would be much better.

Let me know if further information is needed